# emacs elpa load packages

Tags: software-installation, emacs, load

I am using `emacs24`, and I started using `elpa` to download the packages to `~/.emacs.d/elpa` folder.

How can I load these packages?

For instance, I have tried (see below) for `rainbow-delimiter` but it doesn't work.  I have tried commenting out a few lines and keeping others but nothing sticks.

```
;; Paren checking                                                                    
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")                 
(require 'rainbow-delimiters)                                                       
(autoloads (global-rainbow-delimiters-mode rainbow-delimiters-mode-enable           
                                           rainbow-delimiters-mode)                                                                
(global-rainbow-delimiters-mode)                                                    
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)                                 
;(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)                                      
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the default elpa settings, the `.el` files will be installed in subdirectories of `~/.emacs.d/elpa`.  When you use require, it doesn't recursively search the directories in your load path.  To get this effect, you can use the following snippet:

```
(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/elpa"))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```